# Angular workspaces interaction

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-cli-v6

**I am using angular 6.**

Let us assume i have angular 6 project with 2 additional projects (not library) with the following description:

**Project1 :** has one component **app-project1**.

**Project2 :** has one component **app-project2**.

In the default project **app-root** i wanna use the **app-project1** and **app-project2** like that:

Template of **app-root**:

```
<h1> The first project </h1>
<app-project1></app-project1>
<h1> The second project </h1>
<app-project2></app-project2>
```

When i do **ng serve** i got error says that **app-project1** and **app-project2** is not a known component.

My question is how can angular 6 projects communicate with each other or with the default project.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reuse the **older project component** you should **Architecture** your older project 
 component with the approach of  [Sharing Modules](https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules) now you 
 can  reuse the sharded Modules by just copy and paste it in the current project and **import** 
 it on **app-root**

[**Creating a Library with the Angular CLI**](https://blog.angularindepth.com/creating-a-library-in-angular-6-87799552e7e5)

Comment: Thank you for your response,  it's the old way of sharing modules. what i want to use the new workspace feature from angular that added in v6 of Angular.

Comment: @Nour well, i think this article will help you https://blog.angularindepth.com/creating-a-library-in-angular-6-87799552e7e5